# I moved to US recently from India and I am looking for Plastic jars for storage,

Tags: storage-lifetime

I generally store lentils/spices in plastic jars/bottles cos they are not heavy and can be handled easily unlike glass ones .

I am finding it tough to get them in Walmart,Dollar Store.Is there any store I can get them.Checked Amazon too but they have only food storage plastic boxes

Comment: Why not use storage boxes instead? They are widely available, cheap and will do the job just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Run a search for something called "Snap-Ware." Tough, durable, airtight, and very stable plastic. It's even recommended by David Suzuki as a storage medium. Granted, a lot of people consider him alarmist, but he knows his stuff when it comes to bisphenol-A and neoestrogens. I've been using the same Snap-Ware containers for 13 years, and not one has broken, discolored, degraded or had its seal fail.